# Click datepicker element, not the calendar one, but button on the same pane

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, datepicker, webdriver

I'm trying to click first "Today" button,it fills in the date, see code:

```
<div class="ui-datepicker-buttonpane ui-widget-content">
<button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-current ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all" data-handler="today" data-event="click">Today</button>
<button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-close ui-state-default ui-priority-primary ui-corner-all" data-handler="hide" data-event="click">Done</button>
</div>
```

It is a "ui-datepicker-buttonpane ui-widget-content" and looks like this:
[image]

I'm able to use following to open it:

```
Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("NotAfterUtc")).Click();
```

But trying to click it doesn't work.

```
            IWebElement button1 =     Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.TagName("button"));
            IList<IWebElement> buttons1 =     button1.FindElements(By.LinkText("Today"));

            foreach (IWebElement i in buttons1)
            {
                if (i.Text.Equals("Today"))
                {
                    i.FindElement(By.LinkText("Today")).Click();
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better use css-selector rather than xpath for selecting that element as follows:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button.ui-datepicker-current"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @OarpitO, this really saved my day!

Comment: Just did @OarpitO, if not too much hassle please vote up my question as it seems valid. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is not a link it is a button. Use `"//button[contains(text(),'Today')]"` xpath

Comment: Thanks     @Grasshopper, just tested this method and works either.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not have to test Datepicker, because is not your code.
So at my tests i write to set directely DateTime.Now, something like this:

```
Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("NotAfterUtc").send_keys(DateTime.Now);
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @Ulisses Silva, this actually didn't work for me, but I might use it elsewhere.

Actually, you are right I shouldn't be testing Datepicker, but it is just a part of my scenario and I have to use this component. I'm not explicitly testing it.

Best